# mdg:geolocation seems to run differently on my localhost than on myApp.meteor.com

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, meteor

I wrote an emergency services app that gets the user's location and allows them to call local emergency services.  It works fine on my localhost and somewhat fine on my iphone (using `meteor run ios-device`), but when I run it on meteor's server (from `meteor deploy myApp.meteor.com`), the browser never prompts me to allow location services as it does when I run on localhost, and thus, the app doesn't work.

Here's my code in the /client directory:

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
 Tracker.autorun(function () {
  var geo = Geolocation.latLng();
  Session.set('geo', geo);
 }); 
});
```

Any ideas/suggestions?  thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to replace `Geolocation.latLng()` by `Geolocation.currentLocation()` to check if it returns a position or null ?

Is there a git repo ?

Comment: Ah, fixed it!  It turned out I had a private variable in a client/lib file.  I guess the namespacing is stricter than I thought it was.  You still helped though because I needed to scrutinize my log better

Comment: Ahah Nice ! I'm happy for you :)

Comment: @Benjamin what if it returns null on console.log(geo)?